# How to make grid-view-like with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, web

I am kinda new in web developing, I am trying to achieve Grid-view-like layout with column and width that provided by bootstrap but I can't seem to figure how to set the start of each item exactly after item on top of it. And, one more thing my items is dynamic so I don't know what's the height of it.

[image: the item has blank spot on top of it because they have different height]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For dynamic gird view like the one you want can be done through a library called [Salvattore](https://github.com/rnmp/salvattore). Its a script that will help you organize your HTML elements according to the number of columns you specify. Example :
**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="board" data-columns>
            <!-- Now here you can repeat these items with PHP -->
            <div class="items">
               <!-- your content -->
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.column{float:left;}

@media screen and (max-width:480px){
    .column{float:none;position:relative;clear:both;}
}

.size-1of4{width:25%;}
.size-1of3{width:33.333%;}
.size-1of2{width:50%;}
#board[data-columns]::before{content:'4 .column.size-1of4';}

/*--Configure salvattore with media queries--*/

@media screen and (max-width:450px){
    #board[data-columns]::before{content:'1 .column';}
}
@media screen and (min-width:451px) and (max-width:700px){
    #board[data-columns]::before{content:'2 .column.size-1of2';}
}
@media screen and (min-width:701px) and (max-width:850px){
    #board[data-columns]::before{content:'3 .column.size-1of3';}
}
@media screen and (min-width:851px){
    #board[data-columns]::before{content:'4 .column.size-1of4';}
}
```

The above code will produce 4 columns see image below.

[image]

Also don't forget to use salvattore minified js.. :)

Comment: i achieved that, but what i want is each item of second row to start depending on item on top of it, maybe col 3 of row 1 has lower height so col 3 of row 2 start exactly below it, not depending on highest item.

Comment: as your questions says your items are dynamic, then you should use this https://github.com/rnmp/salvattore. And the above code always starts the items directly below the item above it.

Comment: What my code says.. use only one row instead of two or three etc and use cols just only 4 times and place all your items in those 4 cols.

Comment: i guess your suggestion for using salvattore is the only available answer right now. i will accept your answer, but can you edit your original answer and add salvattore in it? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try something like :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4">First</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Second</div>
<div class="col-md-4">Third</div>
</div>
```

This will give you 3 columns . Also check bootstrap docs at [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

**With CSS** - Use display table and table-cell.

```css
body{
  background: #dedede;
}
.row{
  display:table;
  margin: 0 -10px 0;
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing: 20px 10px; /*use border-spacing instead of margins*/
}
.col-sm-4{
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow 0 0 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  float:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively,

**With JS**
You can use Match Height its a jquery based plugin.

http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/